# Why is every top form on a non-compact manifold exact? (without invoking Poincare duality)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M$ be a connected, orientable $n$-manifold without boundary. A well known fact is that the top cohomology $H^n(M, \mathbb{R})$ vanishes if and only if $M$ is not compact, but I have not been able to find an intuitive proof.

One direction is simple. If $M$ is compact, then any volume form is closed but not exact—if it were exact, it would integrate to zero. This proves $M$ compact $\Rightarrow$ $H^n(M, \mathbb{R}) \neq 0.$

There are a few questions on math.SE about the reverse direction, but all of the answers invoke Poincare duality: for non-compact $M$, we have $H^n(M, \mathbb{R}) = H_0^{c}(M) = 0.$ I feel it should be possible to prove the desired statement without any knowledge of singular homology, and would like a proof along those lines.

So the question is this: *why, on a non-compact orientable manifold, is every top form exact?*

Comment: The vague idea is that locally we can always find a form that witnesses exactness, and the obstruction to this being a global form is that the pieces must fit together. The proof is then going to proceed by arguing that we can push the issue to “infinity” since it is noncompact. A similar argument comes up when arguing about the edactness of the totalization of double complex (some exercise in Weibel).

Comment: @ConnorMalin Interesting. Can you be a bit more precise by what you mean when you say "a form that witnesses exactness"? I have been thinking that perhaps the idea is that you can locally write any form as dx \wedge dy (for a 2-form, say) in a sufficiently small neighborhood of any point, though I'm not sure this is the case...

Comment: Because the de Rham cohomology of Euclidean space is trivial, locally any form is exact.